# Proof that the series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{[\Omega(n)]^\alpha}{n^2}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, dirichlet-series

Let's consider the series
$$f(\alpha)=\sum_{n\gt1}\frac{[\,\Omega(n)\,]^\alpha}{n^2}$$
where $\Omega(n)$ denotes the number of prime factors of $n$ counted with their multiplicity and $\alpha\ge0$ is a real parameter.

It is known that
$$f(0)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1$$
and by computational experiments results that
$$f\Big(\frac 1 2\Big)=0.74587577\dots$$
$$f(1)=0.90748082\dots$$
$$f(2)=1.62036452\dots$$
**How to prove that $f(\alpha)$ is finite (that is the given series converges) for any value of $\alpha$?**

The trend of the function $\log f(\alpha)$ is shown in the following graph:

[image]

One could conjecture that
$$f(\alpha)\sim e^{C\alpha}$$
with $C=\frac 5 2$ approximately.

**How to prove this estimate?**

Comment: A number $n$ has at most $\log_{2}(n) = \frac{\log(n)}{\log(2)}$ not necessarily distinct prime factors with equality for $n$ a power of $2$. This guarantees the convergence. I have no idea for the estimate of $f(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The finiteness (and the asymptotics) follow by partial summation from the estimate that the summatory function of $\Omega(n)^a$ is $x (\log \log x)^a$ [See The Wikipedia article](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Prime_omega_function) for the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Too long of a comment. How did you come up with your estimate? If I set $$\Omega(n)=\{n_1+...+n_i+... | n=p_1^{n_1} \cdots p_i^{n_i} \cdots\}$$
for a finite number of $n_i\neq 0$, then $\Omega(n)=k$ includes all the numbers of the form $n=2^k,3^k,5^k,...$ besides mixed numbers and so
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(\Omega(n))^\alpha}{n^2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{\substack{n=2 \\ \Omega(n)=k}}^\infty \frac{k^\alpha}{n^2} \geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}} \frac{k^\alpha}{p^{2k}} \geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{k^\alpha}{2^{2k}} \\
\sim \int_0^\infty {\rm d}k \, k^\alpha 4^{-k} = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}{(\log 4)^{\alpha+1}} \sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi \alpha}}{\log 4} \left(\frac{\alpha}{e\log 4}\right)^\alpha$$
which is eventually larger than your $\sim e^{5\alpha/2}$ asymptotics.